# SQL Server - Move duplicate records into a different table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2019

Employee_table

| Id | FirstName | LastName | Division |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | Smith | A |
| 2 | Emily | Jones | B |
| 3 | John | Smith | B |
| 4 | John | Snow | A |
| 5 | John | Smith | C |

I want to move all duplicate names from Employee_table to a table named Dupes. Dupes has the all the same columns as Employee_table (assume both tables have more columns after Division).

In the table above, there are 3 dupes of John Smith, so all three need to be **moved** to Dupes (within a Transaction). How do I achieve that?

EDIT: Can we keep the query as simple as possible? I am new to SQL (this is not homework).

Comment: SQL Server 2008 or 2012? The former is *completely* unsupported (has been for almost 3 years) and the latter is very close to the end of it's life cycle. Most certainly, regardless of which, you should be well into getting your upgrade path completed.

Comment: Removed those tags

Comment: So what version *are* you using?

Comment: SQL Server 2019.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, we might create a query to find which rows duplicate as question logic from `Employee_table` table.

So we can use `COUNT` window function which is greater than one to represent duplicate as this [sqlfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019l&fiddle=6e91b4be1d5ed99ab29bd149d76278c2)

```
;WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT *,COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY FirstName,LastName) cnt
    FROM Employee_table 
)
SELECT * 
FROM CTE
WHERE cnt > 1
```

Then we can use `DELETE` clause with `CTE` and filter `cnt > 1` which means duplicate rows as this [sqlfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019l&fiddle=a5c6050e905d94371560cbf814374108)

```
;WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT *,COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY FirstName,LastName) cnt
    FROM Employee_table 
)
DELETE CTE
WHERE cnt > 1
```

Final, we can combine before stop and use [`DELETE`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019l&fiddle=12986f9c27f85dad43c7074997556e2d) with [`OUTPUT .... INTO`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/output-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) to `Dupes` table, we can use [`deleted`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/output-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) to get deleted row from `OUTPUT`

```
;WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT *,COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY FirstName,LastName) cnt
    FROM Employee_table 
)
DELETE FROM CTE 
OUTPUT deleted.id,
       deleted.FirstName,
       deleted.LastName,
       deleted.Division
INTO Dupes (id,FirstName,LastName,Division)
WHERE cnt > 1
```

[sqlfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019l&fiddle=12986f9c27f85dad43c7074997556e2d)

Comment: Is there a way to write this query using less complex syntax? I am new to SQL.

Comment: Hi @bigShaq Because you are doing `INSERT` to table from another  `DELETE` table in a transaction which might be a little complex, I would add more explain for you as possible, one second

Comment: Please note, Dupes has the same columns as Employee_table.

Comment: Hi @bigShaq I had edited my answer and tried to explain more detail as possible (split all steps) hope that help